# how can I train a OpenAI fine tuned model with more prompts

Tags: openai-api

I fine-tuned OpenAI model with some prompts following this [documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) it succeeded and created a new model in the playground. How I can retrain (fine-tune) that same model with new prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found out on Open AI [Documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/continue-fine-tuning-from-a-fine-tuned-model)

> If you have already fine-tuned a model for your task and now have additional training data that you would like to incorporate, you can continue fine-tuning from the model. This creates a model that has learned from all of the training data without having to re-train from scratch.

i.e you can't train the already existing trained model again.